# application insights instrumental key when move to new subscription?

Tags: azure, move, azure-application-insights

I'm moving application insight recourses to a new subscription in azure. Question is will instrumental key and Connection String change when moving?

/Martin

Answer (score 3):

Briefly - Application Insights Instrumental key and Connection String will be the same

Azure Application Insights can be moved to another Subscription.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftinsights

Answer (score 1):

Moving resource only changes resource ID, while instrument key and connection string are not related to it, so it won't change.

[image]

But before you move to new subscription, you also need to check the details, see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#checklist-before-moving-resources).

Comment: Thanks i simply could not find a clear answer.
From what i under stand . moving resources between subscriptions does not alter the elements inside the resources or ?

Comment: Basically yes, it's not friendly for developers if moving resource group or subscription will cause elements changing. But as the doc which I provided says, it must change the resource id, but this id is rarely used, and such as azure role assigned to the resource won't move, these are tips which are easy to ignore but always not important. You wanna move an app insights, this resource usually affects production environment a little.